# Core Data not saving updates when doing it programmatically.

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, restkit

I'm using CoreData and I would like to update one of attributes in one of my models, but I can't get it to work using dot notation. My update action looks like this:

```
- (void)addNewsPostToFavourites:(UIButton *)sender
{
    // Returns the right id.
    NSLog(@"Sender tag: %d", sender.tag);

    NSNumber *newsPostId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:sender.tag];
    NewsPost *currentNewsPost = [NewsPost findFirstByAttribute:@"newsPostId" withValue:newsPostId]; 
    // Doesn't seem to do anything.
    currentNewsPost.favourite = @"true";  
}
```

I have also tried `[currentNewsPost setValue:@"true" forKey:@"currentNewsPost.favourite"];` but that gives me the same result, nothing happens.

I therefore wonder what I'm doing wrong.

Should also mention that I use RestKit in my project too.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to save your current context after your update :

```
[self.context save:nil] // You can put an NSError;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, got it to work and you were 99% right. However It looked slightly different when using RestKit, `[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].objectStore save:nil];`. Thanks.

Comment: Oh ok I didn't notice you were using RESTKit. You're welcome !